# How to insert value in NULL from another corresponding row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to join for 3 tables, so that some null values in result, can be replaced.

I tried this:

```
SELECT        ISNULL(Culture,CultureInfoCode) as Culture, ISNULL(Name,'NA') as Name,  ISNULL(Value,'NA') as Value
FROM            SiteLanguages Left JOIN
                         WebDbResources ON SiteLanguages.CultureInfoCode = WebDbResources.Culture Left JOIN
                         KeyWebDbResources ON WebDbResources.KeyWebDbResourceID = KeyWebDbResources.KeyWebDbResourceID
                         where Status=1
```

Here is the result

```
Culture  Name                                                 Value
en-US    Key_FirstName                                        John
TR       NA(Here It should also be Key_FirstName)             NA (ok)
```

But I want Name field in second row as Key_FirstName and Value NA (For corresponding TR Culture).

Here is the schema:

SiteLanguages:

```
CultureInfoCode Status
en-US            1
TR               1
AR               0
```

KeyWebDbResources:

```
KeyWebDbResourceID  Name
1                   Key_FirstName
```

WebDbResources:

```
WebDbResourceID  KeyWebDbResourceID   Culture   Value
1                   1                  en-US    FirstName
```

Second translation does not exist for TR, that's why I want to Fill null on join having Culture and key.

Comment: Just add another criteria on the second join `AND WebDbResources.Culture=SiteLanguages.CultureInfoCode`

Comment: @KPR  you want NA `Replaced` with Key_FirstName NA .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start joining from `KeyWebDbResources` and cross join the `SiteLanguages` to get all the texts that should be there. Left outer join to `WebDbResources` to find the texts that are actually found.

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(SiteLanguages.Culture, CultureInfoCode) as Culture, 
  ISNULL(KeyWebDbResources.Name,'NA') as Name,  
  ISNULL(WebDbResources.Value,'NA') as Value
from KeyWebDbResources 
  cross join SiteLanguages 
  left outer join WebDbResources 
    ON WebDbResources.KeyWebDbResourceID = KeyWebDbResources.KeyWebDbResourceID 
    AND WebDbResources.Culture = SiteLanguages.CultureInfoCode
where SiteLanguages.Status=1
```

The problem then is that you don't get the culture ....

Comment: On inner join it gives error as: The multi-part identifier "WebDbResources.Culture" could not be bound.

Comment: Look at the most recent changes. I fixed it.